# I can't build Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have HTML code:

```
<tr class="odd"><td style="display:none">id&gt;26847504,level&gt;0,key_left&gt;0,key_right&gt;0,name&gt;Random.Stuff345345,type&gt;
```

I want to get those:

1. 26847504
2. Random.Stuff345345

I already tried that:

```
<tr class=\".+\"><td style=\"display:none\">id&gt;([0-9]+),level&gt;0,key_left&gt;0,key_right\&gt;0,name&gt;([^,]+),type&gt;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse HTML.  Use an HTML parser.  In C#, try HTMLAgilityPack

Comment: @Jason: It doesn't really apply here, the contents are just text.

Comment: Are you sure that's *exactly* the HTML source (e.g. no spaces, double-escapes and such)? And could you please post the code you're using to match it?

Comment: All right. It is working. It didn't work in Notepad++, but in .NET it's working. Why is that?

Comment: @user1544261: Ah, that explains it. Notepad++, sadly, has the worst regular expression support I've ever seen. Most expressions won't work (or won't work the way you expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **very bad idea to parse HTML with regex**, but if you want to...

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "...";
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"id&gt;([^,]*).*?name&gt;([^,]*)");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Test the code [here](http://ideone.com/77N6e).